# Environmental Error while installing pytube

Tags: python, pip, installation, pytube

Please help me , I'm new in programming.
Problem : I'm getting environmental error while installing pytube module using command prompt.
First I installed pytube using pycharm only. But when I used it in my code I was getting ImportError so I tried to install pytube using pip in command prompt. But I am getting EnvironmentalError.

What should I do.[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pXtIX.gif) [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0oRfh.gif)

Answer (score 0):

Try typing in the command prompt: `pip install --user pytube`

Answer (score 0):

just run your command prompt as administrator,
it happened because you are trying to install a package that needs admin privileges.
and if you need to install it with your PyCharm IDE, so give PyCharm admin privileges by run it as administrator.